# "would I need" or "will I need" What is the correct sentence?

Tags: word-choice, modal-verbs

I don't know which sentence is correct for my formal letter?

1. As a foreigner will I need any work permit or personal accident insurance?
2. As a foreigner would I need any work permit or personal accident insurance?

My teacher said that "will" is not correct but she also said that "summer" has to be "Summer", so I don't know if this sentence is correct or incorrect.

Comment: *Will* is correct, as is *would*. Summer doesn't need to be capitalised according to three dictionaries I checked, unless it's at the start of a sentence.

Comment: I agree with Jez’s answer, except I believe that “As a foreigner” needs to be followed by a comma. (And, of course, “Summer” is capitalized if it’s a person’s name, but not a season.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are both correct. The *would* one sounds less direct and is probably a good choice if you want to be somewhat polite.

Answer (score 7):

*Would* sounds conditional or hypothetical, so it should be used when expressing a possibility rather than an expected event.  For example:

> I am going abroad to Russia.  As a foreigner will I need any work permit or personal accident insurance?
>   I might go abroad to Russia.  As a foreigner would I need any work permit or personal accident insurance?

Answer (score -2):

"Would" is more polite than "will" (cf Noah). But it still bears a hint of your own wish or will.

I would write "Should", which is submissive to the regulations, and that you have no idea to challenge them.

Comment: “should I get” or “should I have” are acceptable alternatives; “should I need” is not.